# Queueing model without steady state

Tags: queuing-theory

The questions says:

A printer is used to process print jobs. The interarrival times between jobs are exponentially distributed with a mean of 70 seconds. The time that is required to perform a job is exponentially distributed with a mean of 35 seconds.

a) Assume that 2 printers are used to process the incoming print jobs. Determine the mean
time an incoming job has to wait until it can be processed (in seconds).

So I tried to figure this out:

In seconds: $\lambda=70$, $\mu=35$, $\rho=\frac{70}{35}=2$ we have two printers so my $c=2$.

Now to see if there's a steady state: $\frac{\rho}{c}=\frac{2}{2}=1\nless1$, so there is no steady state.

So with the formulas I know I can't calculate the Wq, can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Don't we actually have $\lambda=1/70$ and $\mu=1/35$ (from which $\rho=1/4$)?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire This works thanks, why do we have to do this tho?

Comment: Why you have to do what exactly?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Why it is 1/70 and not just 70. Because 70 is also in seconds or did I miss the definition of lambda?

Comment: $\lambda$ is the mean arrival *rate*. An interarrival time of $70$ seconds means one arrival every $70$ seconds (so $1/70$ per second). If $\lambda=70$ that would mean $70$ arrivals per second.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks for clarifying that, I get it now

Answer (score 0):

Most of the formulas I have come across in queueing theory assume steady state, and I don't know of a purely mathematical approach for all cases. So let me show you a simple simulation approach.

Using [Ciw](https://ciw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), let us simulate for $10^4$ jobs.

```py
import ciw
import pandas as pd

ciw.seed(2018)


network = ciw.create_network(
    arrival_distributions = [ciw.dists.Exponential(1/70)],
    service_distributions = [ciw.dists.Exponential(1/35)],
    number_of_servers = [2]
    )

simulation = ciw.Simulation(network)

simulation.simulate_until_max_customers(10000)

records = pd.DataFrame(simulation.get_all_records())


print(
    (
        records.waiting_time
        .describe()
        .to_markdown()
        )
    )
```

And here are the results.

|  | waiting_time |
| --- | --- |
| count | 10000 |
| mean | 2.14293 |
| std | 9.50576 |
| min | 0 |
| 25% | 0 |
| 50% | 0 |
| 75% | 0 |
| max | 161.518 |

And here is a plot of the arrival time vs waiting time:

[image]

Comment: Would you say what does the waiting time equal to $160$ mean on top of $300000$ arrival_date?

Comment: @A.Omidi Right, I see that spike. It means that one of the jobs waited on the queue for $\approx 160$ units of time and they arrived on the queue at time $\approx 300000$.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. As the arrival rate is more than the service rate, it seems there would be no queue on the server queue. It is a bit different from what you proposed on the graph. Do you check this?

Comment: @A.Omidi If the arrival and service times were constants of 70s and 35s respectively, then yes there would eventually be a time in which the queue was always empty. In this case we are sampling from exponential distributions where the rates given are the averages, not the sampled outcomes. For a familiar statistical example, men are taller than women on average, but that doesn't mean every man is taller than every woman. Likewise, sometimes more arrivals are sampled than service completion for a given interval of time, even though more completion happens on average than arrivals.

Comment: There are different notions of [stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) if it peaks your interest to get into the mathematics of order relations on statistical populations.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.